# Looking for an approach to save hierarchical data

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm

I'm looking for a solution to replace our actual save algorithm for a hierarchical structured data since we have major performance issues.

Our hierarchical structured data consist in 2 tables (`observation`, `value`). Here are the specification for each of these entity:

- Observation

  - Can contain 0..* child observations (maximum depth of 10 levels including value depth)
  - Has 0..* value
  - Has one parent which can be

    - Document (root entity of the hierarchical structure)
    - Observation
    - Value
- Value

  - Has 0..* child observation (maximum depth of 10 levels including observation depth)
  - Has one parent observation

The stripped T-SQL definitions for `observation` and `value` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Observation(
            Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            DocumentParentId int NULL,
            ObsParentId int NULL,
            ValueParentId int NULL,
            EditionDate Datetime NOT NULL,
            State tinyint NOT NULL,
            Comment varchar(max) NULL,
            CONSTRAINT [PK_Observation] PRIMARY KEY (Id) 
)

CREATE TABLE Value(
            Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            ObservationId int NOT NULL,
            Data varchar(max) NULL,
            CONSTRAINT PK_Value PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

**Current save algorithm (simplified)**

Iteration though the first level of observation

```
foreach (Observation obs in doc.Roots)
{
   obs.SaveObservation(doc.Id, null, null, connection)
}
```

Save logic for the `observation` entity :

```
public void SaveObservation(int? docParentId, int? obsParentId, int? valParentId, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans)
{
            string sql =
                            @"INSERT INTO Observation (DocumentParentId, ObsParentId, ValueParentId, EditionDate, State, Comment)
             VALUES (@docId, @oparentId, @vparentId, @date, @state, @comment)
             SELECT scope_identity())";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn, trans);
            if (docParentId.HasValue)
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@docId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = docParentId.Value;
            else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@docId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;

            if (obsParentId.HasValue)
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@oparentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = obsParentId.Value;
            else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@oparentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;

            if (valParentId.HasValue)
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@vparentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = valParentId.Value;
            else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@vparentId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;
            //... insert internal properties


            this.Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();  //insert and obtains id

            foreach (Observation child in this.Children)
                            this.SaveObservation(null, this.Id, null, conn, trans);

            foreach (Value val in this.Values)
                            val.SaveValue(this.Id, conn, trans);
}
```

Save logic for the `value` entity :

```
public void SaveValue(int parentobs, SqlConnection conn, SqlTransaction trans)
{
            //save value with an insert sql command
            //...

            foreach(var obs in this.Dependents)
                             obs.SaveObservation(null, null, this.Id, conn, trans);
}
```

In this current algorithm, their is one request on the database for each `observation` and `value` entity to insert.
With a test, 10 000 observation values, it takes 2 seconds to save document (in test environment, one user only).

I tried to change our current algorithm so that the server would send only one request for the complete save logic.

**First test (stringbuilder)**

My first idea was to use a string builder to write all the insert commands in one string and to execute that string on SQL afterwards.
for an observatin I wrote

```
DECLARE @obs int 
insert ...
Set @obs  = SELECT scope_identity()
etc.
```

For my test document, the logic created a string of 15 meg. SQL failed when executing the query because it had over 10 000 declared variable.

**Second test (stored procedure & table parameters)**

Staging table for Observation

```
CREATE TYPE SaveObservationType AS TABLE(
                ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                DocParentId int NULL,
                ObsParentID uniqueidentifier NULL,
                ValueParnetID uniqueidentifier NULL,
                ... 
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
                [ID] ASC
)
```

Staging table for Value

```
CREATE TYPE SaveObservationValueType AS TABLE(
                ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                ObservationID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
                ...
                PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
                ID ASC
)
)
```

In c# I navigate through my structure and insert guids as temporary ids and fill the staging tables.

In the stored procedure, I have a cursor to navigate through the first level of observations, a cursor for the children of the observation, and a cursor for child observations of a value.

For large data this is very slow (~3 times slower that the current algorithm),
but for a small data it takes the same time.  I thinks that the performance issue is caused by the use of cursors.
I use cursors because I need  to insert each observation one at a time to obtain it's id  that will be used when I navigate through his childrens and values.

Third test (bulk copy & stored procedure):

I bulk copy my data in a staging table `SaveObservationValue`. Afterwards I call the stored procedure to navigate the records in this table to insert the data in the database.  This is similar to the second test, for the exception that the staging table has indexes.

Each  record  of the table contains observation data or value data.
In the stored procedure, I use a cursor to navigate the structure.

For large data (6000 observations and values) it takes about 3 sec (50% slower that my current algorithm).  In this test, the bottleneck of the performance is the stored procedure (2.5 sec) probably due to the use of the cursors.

**Summary**

The 3 approaches I tested weren't conclusive.  In each case, the current algorithm it the fastest but it is still (in my opinion) slow and demanding on the network (server and database are on 2 different machine).

- Is their a way to save this hierarchical data in a more efficient way?

  - What is causing my performance issue (the design itself)?
  - Is their a more efficient way to save hierarchical data other then the cursor approach I took in my 3 tests?

Comment: Have you considered using a document-based storage approach? Apart from the NoSQL options, SQL Server supports some XML features, and I believe the latest version is adding some JSON support as well.

Comment: So why is it a potential problem ie. I want to understand why 2 to 3 seconds is not acceptable? Is it because there are too many incoming save requests and the database server will "choke"? Is there some other reason?

Comment: Also have you considered using [Sql Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)?

Comment: In the bulk & store procedure test you think performance might be due to the use of cursors. How are the cursors created ? are you using the local fast_forward option when declaring your cursors ?

Comment: @igor The 2-3 seconds is acceptable but I would prefer it to be faster.  The reason is that my tests were made in a sandbox environment with only 1 user.  In the actual production environment we can have up to 100 concurrent users that can each trigger concurrent saves which will most likely make the database "choke".

Comment: @GuidoG I tried `DECLARE ROOTCUR CURSOR FAST_FORWARD  FOR `.   I don't see that is more fast . .but thanks for this suggestion